# ImportError: No module named... in __init__.py file

Tags: python, flask, python-import

My project structure is:

```
/home/giri/couponmonk_project
    __init__.py
    views.py
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
import couponmonk_project.views
```

**views.py**

```
from couponmonk_project import app

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    return 'Flask is running!'
```

When I run:

```
gunicorn __init__:app -b localhost:8000
```

from the folder `/home/giri/couponmonk_project`

I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named couponmonk_project.views
```

I tried adding:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/giri/couponmonk_project")
```

to my `__init__.py` file but still get the same error.

Even if this had worked, is appending to `sys.path` the proper way of doing this?

I have read that appending to `sys` and `PYTHONPATH` may not be the best way to fix the issue.

Comment: @l4mpi Sorry that was a typo.

Comment: Seems like you have a circular dependency.

Answer (score 3):

As it has been stated in the above comments you have a circular dependency. To avoid it, you should make your current `couponmonk_project` as module, that will be run by another python script. According to the [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/) your project should look like:

```
/home/giri/couponmonk_project
    __init__.py
    /home/giri/couponmonk_project/couponmonk_project
    __init__.py
    views.py
```

where inner folder `couponmonk_project` is your present project, and outer folder `couponmonk_project` is the new one. Thus, file `/home/giri/couponmonk_project/__init__.py` should be something like:

```
from couponmonk_project import app
import couponmonk_project.views

app.run()
```

and your file `/home/giri/couponmonk_project/coupon_monk/project__init__.py` is:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
```